# Multiple calls to SetOptions with NotebookEventActions: How to retain earlier custom event handlers?

Tags: eventhandler

I have a module defining handlers of KeyDown events that I reuse in various notebooks.  In some cases I need to define separate handlers for additional keys.  Unfortunately, later calls to `SetOptions[...]` seem to undo earlier ones.  For example, I might first evaluate

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], NotebookEventActions -> {
   {"KeyDown", "\ "} :> Speak["Space"],
    "EscapeKeyDown" :> (Speak["Escape"]; 
     SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], NotebookEventActions -> None])}]
```

As a consequence, spacebar presses cause the computer to say "space" until this behavior is cancelled (by pressing the Esc key).  However, if I don't press Esc and evaluate in a separate cell

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], NotebookEventActions -> {
   {"KeyDown", "\.08"} :> Speak["Backspace"],
    "EscapeKeyDown" :> (Speak["Escape"] ; 
     SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], NotebookEventActions -> None])}]
```

the computer correctly responds to "backspace" key presses by speaking but has reverted to the default response to spacebar presses.

How can I get successive event-handler definitions to be cumulative?

(Using Windows 10, Mathematica 11.3.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why can't you just prepend your new actions? For example:

```
SetOptions[
    EvaluationNotebook[],
    NotebookEventActions->{
        {"KeyDown"," "} :> Speak["Space"],
        "EscapeKeyDown" :> (
            Speak["Escape"];
            SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[],NotebookEventActions->None]
        )
    }
];

SetOptions[
    EvaluationNotebook[],
    NotebookEventActions -> Prepend[
        OptionValue[Options @ EvaluationNotebook[], NotebookEventActions],
        {"KeyDown", "\.08"} :> Speak["Backspace"]
    ]
];

Options[EvaluationNotebook[], NotebookEventActions]

(*
{NotebookEventActions -> {{"KeyDown", "\.08"} :> 
    Speak["Backspace"], {"KeyDown", " "} :> Speak["Space"], 
   "EscapeKeyDown" :> (Speak["Escape"]; 
     SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], NotebookEventActions -> None])}}
*)
```

Comment: That's great, and so easy!  Thanks so much for the prompt reply.  I guess I expected Mathematica to append additional handlers automatically, and when it didn't, I stopped thinking ...